# How to create a global language selector page at domain root with i18n when the global language has a prefix?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am looking for a solution to create a language selector at www.domain.com. My site has multiple languages (en, de, fr). All the languages are using a domain prefix. This results in:

- www.domain.com/en (default language)
- www.domain.com/de
- www.domain.com/fr

Now I want a global language selector at www.domain.com without any redirects. The module https://www.drupal.org/project/language_selection_page is almost what I'm trying to accomplish, but this is using a redirect. I was told this is bad for SEO (redirect).

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating an index.html file. Then in the .htaccess I changed the default handler from

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

to

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm

This way I am able to create a custom page at the domain root.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a special "homepage" node, for which you set the "language" to "Language Neutral" (any path will do, even no path if that's what you'd prefer). And use its node ID (preceeded by 'Node/') as the value for "*Default front page *" within `admin/config/system/site-information`.

From then on, you can create any content for that node as your language selection page, which of course should include a link to each language specific "starting page".

Comment: This way the URL is not at www.domain.com but will still use the language prefix. For example: www.domain.com/en or www.domain.com/fr

It will show the custom page, but not at www.domain.com.